# How to correct/edit/change UV map when reseaming is not possible and Select Split is not the answer

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I am cleaning a UV for a project and reseaming is not possible for reasons beyond my control. See below:

[image]

I am searching for tools allowing me to correct this tangle of UV verts. I have explored Split Seam and it certainly will be useful for some needs, but not this one. I am looking for mesh-like editing of the verts, allowing me to either move them into place or delete them and recreate.

Is this possible?

Comment: It's likely assigning new seams isn't needed; that could be caused by geometry created after unwrap was done. Try pinning everything on UV map but those verts and unwrap once more. Create one more UV map in order not to mess up original unwrap.

Comment: Select the vertice and press G to move it. Set "Sticky Selection Mode" to disabled. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/introduction.html#header